# How to make fixed CollectionView sticky column or row?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Can anyone suggest how to make a sticky column or row of a CollectionView?

As I understand this feature is available in CollectionViewController but I have some other views so I can go with only CollectionView.

This is the following code I am using for sticking:

```
let layout = collectionViewt.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

But this is not solving my issue. Can anyone kindly suggest how to get the sticky header functionality for my CollectionView?

Need to achieve this by using collectionView not by collectionViewController:

[image: Click Below Link for more clarification]

Comment: The way I've seen it done is to add another view contain the row / column you want to stick and keep it visible as you scroll.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pbU3BRqa7A you can go with this tutorial to make sticky header

Comment: kindly please check my question just now Edited and Updated screenshot also this thing i have to achieve by CollectionView not by CollectionViewController

Comment: check this out  for example: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView You definitely need custom Subclass of UICollectionViewLayout